# JQuery auto meta tag description

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the first class and apply the same text into a meta description, but the meta isn't loading in the var get.  Can someone take a look and debug this?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// add the class of first to any element to get the meta data to populate
var get = $('.first').html();
var myclone = $('meta[name=description]').attr("content");
$(get).appendTo(myclone);
//alert(get);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand which way you are going.  Would you like the value of "content" in your meta tag to populate the .first element, or the content of .first element to populate the "content" of your meta tag?

Comment: So var get = "this is a description" meta content="get"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get what you're trying to do but I would **not** recommend it.  You can't count on search engines to run your javascript so unless you're using the description meta info for something completely unrelated to describing your pages content for search engines, you could be trying to do something here which is a waste of effort.  Your description should be coming back in your original HTML, and not rendered from javascript.

That being said, if you really want to keep doing what you're doing...

```
$('meta[name=description]').attr("content", $('.first').text());
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.  I know it isn't ideal but it's what the client wants.

Comment: If the client wants the description to be specific to each page (as it should per Google's own SEO guide pg 6 - http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf), that is very reasonable request, but it needs to be done server side and inserted into the HTML.  But, if the clients literal request is "do this in javascript" then have at it.